# Spring - YAML config not found when autowiring service into another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am currently working on a project consisting of several modules which are all spring managed. I am now trying to autowire a service of module A into module B. This service is configured using a `application.yml` config file in module A. When using a standalone version of module A everything is working fine and config values are correctly injected into the fields annotated with `@Value("${...}")`. But if I use this service from module B, its construction fails due to spring being unable to resolve the placeholders given in the annotations.

So it seems like autowiring the service into another project renders it unable of finding the config file. Is there any way of resolving this issue?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: This is how the relevant parts of the config class look:

```
    @EnableKafka
    @Configuration
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "...")
    public class ElasticsearchConfig {

            @Value("${elasticsearch.home}")
            private String elasticsearchHome;

            @Value("${elasticsearch.cluster}")
            private String clusterName;

            @Bean
            public Client client() {
                 Settings elasticSettings = Settings
                    .builder()
                    .put("path.home", elasticsearchHome)
                    .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                    .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                    .build();
                 PreBuiltTransportClient client = 
                    new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticSettings);
                 try {
                    client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
                 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
                 return client;

            }
         ...
       }
```

These values are then used to create the beans necessary to build an elasticsearch client . The corresponding application.yml looks something like this:

```
elasticsearch:
  cluster: elasticsearch
  home: "/path/to/elasticsearch-6.4.2/"

kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  ...
```

Here is the relevant part of the project structure:

```
Project
|-- module A
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   `-- java
|       |       |-- ElasticsearchConfig.java
|       |       |-- SomeService.java
|       |       `-- ServiceUsedFromA.java
|       `-- resources
|           `-- application.yml
`-- module B
    `-- src
        `-- main
            |-- java
            |   `-- ServiceUsedFromB.java
            `-- resources
                `-- ...
```

If `SomeService` is autowired in `ServiceUsedFromA` everything is working as expected, if autowired into `ServiceUsedFromB` (which is also spring based) the above mentioned issue occurs.

Comment: how are you using application.yml to inject beans in your application??? can you post some code to help us figure it out

Comment: @slimane Added snippets of config class and application.yml for clarification.

Comment: Can you explain how you are - " using this service from module B"? How you are managing module dependencies?

Comment: @shakhawat They are managed using maven. Module A is registered as a dependency in module B's pom.

Comment: your settings are pretty clean, I'm afraid you are passing the wrong path, did you make sure that your path doesn't end with /?

Comment: @slimane What path exactly do you mean? If you are refering to the elasticsearch path - it is not causing the issue. Concerning the application.yml, I am not passing a path to it anywhere - it is autodetected by spring boot.

Comment: I mean this one: elasticsearchHome

Comment: @slimane What would I have to change? Why is it working when used from its own module?

Comment: can you post your project structure?

Comment: @slimane Added the project structure.

Comment: @TreeMage more interesting information, are you sure that all your packages are scan by your app from module B?

Comment: @slimane They are, since spring would report that there is no qualifing bean to autowire if it couldnt resolve the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a substantial amount of searching and trying out different ideas to fix the issue, I have finally found a solution:

I switched from using a YAML config file to using `application.properties` placed in the resource folder mentioned in the project structure posted above. This allowed me to specify the property file via a `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")` annotation in `ElasticSearchConfig.java` (which is not possible for YAML configs). 
Now spring seems to be able to pick up the config file, even if the service is autowired into another module.

Thanks for your effort :)